# "On behalf of" or "On the behalf of"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage, definite-articles

> - Ability to do X on the behalf of another user

vs

> - Ability to do X on behalf of another user

Which one is correct and why? :(

I've been debating this with someone over the copy of some app release notes - we ended up totally rewording it to flow better but I'd still like to know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary it is a phrase without any article
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20behalf%20of:

***on behalf of***

or in behalf of

: in the interest of

also : as a representative of

// I wrote the letter on behalf of my client